# How could I properly configure Solr to index my Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, solr, lucene

I've been trying to configure **Solr** to work with my **Oracle 11.2** database as a datasource but nothing works. I have thoroughly explored the documentations and it seems to lack a good and working guide.

---

**For a simple scenario, I want to index my single table [topic]**

The structure of my table ***topic*** is shown below:

> - ID (autonumber)
> - Topic (varchar 50) ***I want to index this***
> - Info (varchar 255) ***I want to index this***

---

**My solr configurations (so far)**

I have added a new collection for this Oracle, name it ***"oracle_test"***. So I configure the folder structure as guided by the official documentation for this collection as follows:

- ~/solr/server/solr/

  - oracle_test

    - conf

      - data-config.xml
      - elevate.xml
      - schema.xml
      - solrconfig.xml

**data-config.xml**

I have configured a working datasource connection string to my Oracle, specified the query to my ***topic*** table, also the fields I want Solr to look up.

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:system@//127.0.0.1:1521/orcl/" user="system" password="*****"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="help" query="select \"topic\",\"info\" from \"topic\"" dataSource="jdbc">
            <field column="topic" name="topic"/>
            <field column="info" name="info"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**schema.xml**

I put the definitions of fields here.

```xml
<schema name="oracle_help" version="1.1">
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
    <field name="topic" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <defaultSearchField>info</defaultSearchField>
    <field name="topic" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="info" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</schema>
```

**solrconfig.xml**

Since the configuration file is big and it includes everything. I will take only some excerpts from this configuration file which is related to the Oracle configuration as follows:

I specify which field (topic) I want it to index:

```xml
<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="df">topic</str>
    </lst>
</initParams>
```

Under *processor* section, I have only one default field type defined as string:

```xml
<processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
  ...
</processor>
```

---

**Then I tried importing the datasource via Solr Admin**

Using "DataImport" on Solr Admin dashboard, once execute the command, I got this response back which I'm not sure whether it correctly indexed my Oracle table:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1
},
"initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
        "config",
        "data-config.xml"
    ]
],
"command": "status",
"status": "idle",
"importResponse": "",
"statusMessages": {}
}
```

Weird thing is, the status is indicated as "idle".

---

**I tried to execute search query, but it returns error**

Use the search query "test" as follows:

```
$> curl http://localhost:8983/solr/oracle_test/select?q=test&wt=json&indent=true
```

Solr returns me "undefined field topic".

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
        "q": "called",
        "indent": "true",
        "wt": "json",
        "_": "1434341618019"
    }
},
"error": {
   "msg": "undefined field topic",
   "code": 400
  }
}
```

But, as shown at the earlier part, obviously I have already defined the field "topic" in my schema.xml. It seems lack of documentation or guide on Solr official sites and I tried doing some research on Internet, but I've got nothing at all.

Can anybody who might be familiar with Solr - Oracle integration please help me figure this out? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Solr server should generate an error upon start-up or when you are trying to access the index that uses the schema.xml you have defined. Please have a look into the logs of your solr server.

It has formal errors, these prevent the index from starting and in turn the DIH you have defined from running

- `<types />` is missing around your field types
- `<fields />` is missing around your fields
- `<defaultSearchField />` is missplaced inside your fields
- you have defined the field named `topic` twice

The structure of a [schema.xml is documented in Solr's Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml). A valid version of your schema.xml would look like the sample below.

```xml
<schema name="oracle_help" version="1.1">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  </types>

  <defaultSearchField>info</defaultSearchField>

  <fields>
    <field name="topic" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="info" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  </fields>
</schema>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have quickly correct the structure of `schema.xml` accordingly. However, the error 400 which says "undefined field topic" still persist. To my wondering, in the `DataImport` section, I always see the status is shown as `No information available (idle)`. Does this signify any possible cause?

Comment: I have just noticed this line in the Solr log at the startup: "*The schema has been upgraded to managed,​ but the non-managed schema schema.xml is still loadable. PLEASE REMOVE THIS FILE.*"

Comment: Looks like you are using Solr in version 5.X and that you have basic configuration problems. Sorry, there are too many moving parts before you get to run your data-import. Please have a look at the examples provided with the Solr distribution. You will find a DIH example in **solr-5.2.0\example\example-DIH**

Answer (score 0):

The approach which you are using seems to be fine. In solrConfig.xml try using below line

```
<str name="config">/path/to/my/DIHconfigfile.xml</str>
```

instead of `<str name="df">topic</str>`